# Access nested property value via dynamic string literals of object's nested keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to access a value (object) via the keys of a nested object.

Here is an example. I have an object that holds a dynamic number of car brands. Each brand has a dynamic number of models. Each model has an object with information about the car.

[Please see this TS playground for a full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSB6CuAFQAsk4YBPMRiTOAAwGEBBBAGUucYAGdR4ADbA0wGFOZM64gFyVqLNnB4ooEgLxwA3hrjmA2gCMoKAHYATANJJmquGJhRgdgOYBdd1Mqc1CLEAgHJCkXNw8vHwD3XSgASTtMCABuM3MAXxyQgrMAOhKrAFd4VLg0ewByeF9gADdGGBUJJAAPMBk5FiZWdohufiEuABo4CA6kKAB3cXaGeO8-OBkYeZQpCSWpKTgrRnwINsXvGG27fDgW4BRlRi5Pdd8uErMAeShRCTmRDg9lmDD+CxQShgoy0K0YaAgdk800q8BOiWBVikI2BaDQSDEEnk90eawxWx2ewA-KQEUj4ONBHAjKZzCB5viomIgqRQrUpDy+eYxMAAF5IdwARgATABmSa8oUIqTQdz4XxEJC3BV8vI60JoQVCkXi9yy836vnK1UEIgOfCWuB6xXCgUmF2hE0SuDm+Ue8zWqBqu0Oj3O-L6lAVBzAI3mFCyuOesXeyVpx0BiAqoMELEVJCh3WOlAAFiTwpT7gArDWM7UszbCEh7Y7w06FXlgRI6Z4cqRYTo9IYhmwODoBII+wOUgA1PSPOzwIwpLrdG4OCTIBFQBwAHh8mHmcFi0wqdgA1nYIAs7AA+RVU4+uOA9dcSc+uMcrj2PrgAEmMWI4AAMjJPw8hKACP2YL8hwsWJ-BAsDfDyLgPXcOwkAuRUMKw+Y+xCBZoHPMRaURTwmAJGBvicZI9Dnbx7CXAh2SgTkCRKNB8EKagiKgEi4AACkwFBgBkDYejYDBmwASjI+lKM8AA5WYaLoqAGIXZj8AWHA-BKRESjACooEgMQCz7chpz0dJMmZd0K1NOA7AqEATigHJM2zdw3kSHJikoAAqQK4AAcSQeA5lqPRRAyUYHieKKYCIuBoIkQSuBsexnGfABaW84AiKIYjygq6jSOKuBkko4ECihSEwM8MGARE4F8CKUlsiBd0VGgACFbEcIDXy1DdUs-TgV31GgAFlImiYa11G98JsHfQLH6wacuYfxSFvQSsqG1x3E27KT0K+aSriWbLtiGSHPrBTDocABRRcoCUZcJ2sLaEM8x6KPKrr7Oet6vGYcJbtcfw+3MIgYBMuxooqzJ-PIQjiNInt4HKyV7PamBOriwT8CjGMHQIBN8Bkni4D4gThNE8TfBfXokGkhw5Ox5HpXxjqbOJ0no2ACmdL03xcsRXLjNMiBzOpvtucDezcc4hsPPkwH1d5oxyulNXsz7Rq7Ga1qUh68xTqOpQRscFaYMmodprm4rFrfcaHbWsQNoGs7ob2wSwBwMBuRMY4tpO33rayC7ipOl2FufPIZPcAApQQAA0She7F2UXB6Mf40jMwU8q+cJgXMl3K3tumG7Xdcfag4gEPyi26Zm9borohpxUQgcCACWc2Y6eIxUlb0HXxyEH7sv8SHiphxV4cRoSPV3e8hRMCgQoHoer3genaooPJ-TgXcwFvYxyoN6A8l3ChL-XihN7gXvT7MenSN3FJw+ygx8CsXYmIO43cpAAK4nAF+WQgA).

```ts
type CarInfo = {
  size: number;
  color: string;
};

type Cars = {
  // brand
  [brandKey: string]: {
    // model
    [modelKey: string]: {
      size: number;
      color: string;
    };
  };
};

const exampleCars: Cars = {
  mercedes: {
    c: { size: 123, color: "green" },
  },
};
```

In reality, I can't give this object a type, because I want to use the keys as string literals, which would be overwritten by the `string` union.
So my cars look like this:

```ts
const CARS = {
  mercedes: {
    c: {
      size: 333,
      color: "red",
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
} as const;

type Cars = typeof CARS;
```

With that, I can "extract" the string literals and use them in a function to get one specific car info via the brand key and the model key:

```ts
function getCarInfo<
  TBrandKey extends keyof Cars,
  TModelKey extends keyof Cars[TBrandKey]
>(brandKey: TBrandKey, modelKey: TModelKey) {
  const brandEntry = CARS[brandKey];
  const carInfo = brandEntry[modelKey];

  return carInfo;
}
```

Please note that the there is no explicit return, but only an implicit return - more on that further down below.

This now works when calling the function with explicit string literals:

```ts
// works
const car1 = getCarInfo("mercedes", "c");
// works (fails as expected)
const car2 = getCarInfo("audi", "wrong-on-purpose");

// works
const color = car1.color
```

But instead of using fixed string literals, I want to give them through as props of a React component:

```tsx
function Car<
  TBrandKey extends keyof Cars,
  TModelKey extends keyof Cars[TBrandKey]
>(props: { brand: TBrandKey; model: TModelKey }): JSX.Element {
  // works
  const carInfo = getCarInfo(props.brand, props.model);
  // does not work
  const carInfo2 = CARS[brand][model];

  return (
    <>
      {/* does not work */}
      <p>{carInfo.color}</p>
    </>
  );
}

// works
<Car brand="mercedes" model="c" />;
```

Here, the props of the component work as expected. They e.g. give autocomplete for the "model" when providing the "brand".

But I cannot get the car info.

- When having an implicit return of `getCarInfo`, TS doesn't know that `color` exists on `carInfo`.
- When giving `getCarInfo` an explicit return (`CarInfo`), the function itself does not work, as I whatever is found via `brandEntry[modelKey]` is not of type `CarInfo` in TypeScript's world.

What am I missing?

Comment: When using implicit return, you could check the actual return type typescript inferred by hovering over the function in VS Code

Comment: Your code gives me an error at `const brandEntry = CARS[brandKey];` line inside getCarInfo function even when using implicit return, the error is “Type 'TBrandKey' cannot be used to index type…”. I used VSCode ensuring that typescript 4.7.4 version is used to verify that, I even ran `tsc` from command line.

Comment: @niceman Thanks, but I originally added a TS playground at the top of my post, which uses version 4.7.4 - it does not show the error there.

Comment: Yes I know you added a playground and I don't know why it doesn't show the error, anyway the tsc command line compiler is more trustworthy than the playground.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't get the car info, because I reproduced your example locally, assigned the type `Cars` to `CARS`, and I see `<p>{carInfo.color}</p>` outputting the correct value in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing generic functions in a way that TypeScript can check can be difficult. I generally recommend creating wider types for use in the implementation.

Here are a few options:

```
function Car<
  TBrandKey extends keyof Cars,
  TModelKey extends keyof Cars[TBrandKey] & string
>(props: { brand: TBrandKey; model: TModelKey }): JSX.Element {
  let CARS2: Record<string, Record<string, CarInfo>> = CARS;
  const car = CARS2[props.brand][props.model];
  return <p>{car.color}</p>;
}
```

This requires `TModelKey` to extend `string` in addition to the `keyof` because TS doesn't track that there's no symbol key on the object through the indirection of the first generic.

```
function Car<
  TBrandKey extends keyof Cars,
  TModelKey extends keyof Cars[TBrandKey]
>(props: { brand: TBrandKey; model: TModelKey }): JSX.Element {
  let CARS2: Record<string, Record<PropertyKey, CarInfo>> = CARS;
  const car = CARS2[props.brand][props.model];
  return <p>{car.color}</p>;
}
```

Instead of `& string`, you could also widen the `CARS2` type even more.

---

TypeScript also supports overloaded functions, and a really useful trick occasionally is to define an overloaded function which only has one visible signature, with an easier to work with implementation signature.

This doesn't work great here, but is a useful trick to know:

```
function Car<
  TBrandKey extends keyof Cars,
  TModelKey extends keyof Cars[TBrandKey] & string
>(props: { brand: TBrandKey; model: TModelKey }): JSX.Element
function Car(props: { brand: keyof Cars, model: keyof Cars[keyof Cars] }): JSX.Element {
  const car = CARS[props.brand][props.model];
  //    ^? const car: never - because keyof on an intersection requires common keys
}
``
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand correctly that you propose to use `string` instead of the string literals? So, in other words, what I wanted to do with string literals here is not a good idea?

Comment: @BennettDams, I think using literals is a good idea whenever possible, and it is possible here. The `CARS2` workaround gives the benefits of the literals everywhere it can be used, while making it possible to implement the generic function without type assertions.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm baffled that you can't use the string literals to access the nested property, is this somehow mentioned in the TypeScript docs?

Comment: @BennettDams for TS, `brand` *isn't* a known string literal in your generic implementation, it's "some unknown value that is some key of Cars"... I don't think it's mentioned in the handbook anywhere, there's probably some GitHub issue on the repo which discusses this problem.